# console output from guest (qemu VM) does no carriage return on host console when called with python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, debian, qemu, carriage-return

I installed a virtual machine (guest) via qemu (qemu-system-x86_64) on a linux box (host).
The virtual machine is also linux. On guest I have the following remote_bash_script.sh:

remote_bash_script.sh:

```
for (( count=1; count<=10; ++count )); do
  echo 'test message'
  sleep 1
done
exit 1
```

This script can be called via call_remote_bash_script.py from the host:

call_remote_bash_script.py:

```
import subprocess

my_command = "ssh -t user_name@ip_address \'./remote_bash_script.sh\'"
my_process = subprocess.Popen(my_command, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    my_line = my_process.stdout.readline()
    time.sleep(2)
    if not my_line:
        break
    print(my_line.strip())
```

The output is:

```
test message
            test message
                        test message
                                    test message
                                                test message
                                                            Connection to ip_address closed.
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
```

If I run
ssh -t user_name@ip_address "./remote_bash_script"
off the command line, I get

```
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
test message
Connection to ip_address closed.
user_name_host@host_name:~$
```

**Question: why do I not get a carriage return while the connection is open? How can this be fixed?**

I need output line by line since the process is long running.

The problem may be related with qemu settings, terminal settings or the way I am using Popen.
I can provide more details on my linux and python setup if required.

I did fiddle with alternative subprocess methods as well as Popen arguments.

Comment: `strip()` does this: Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed.....   i wonder if there are other characters to remove ?  (that would be the python side of it).

Answer (score 0):

The result of stdout.readline() includes a trailing newline and no carriage return, because that's the standard in Linux.

Now print seems to look at the string and says: If it is has any kind of newline or carriage return we send it to stdout as is. Otherwise I add a line ending matching the current's OS architecture.

You can fix it by stripping CR and NL from the received string. Then it should work.

```
my_line = my_process.stdout.readline().strip("\n\r")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately that does not solve the problem.  My debugger says that readline() returns "test message\n". strip() or strip("\r\n") or strip("\n\r") removes an empty line but does not do the line feed.